# Html table : appending img to a cell increases the size of the row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

The table is a list of strings, rows are originally 17px in height (that's for a 13px font size). Adding an image of 7x7 px in a cell, the rows get much further apart. I don't know how to do better since the image should be small enough to fit in the cell.

All kinds of borders are already trimed :

```
tableUsers = document.createElement("TABLE");
tableUsers.id = "tableUsers";        
tableUsers.style.tableLayout = "fixed";
tableUsers.style.width = "100%";
tableUsers.style.border = "none";
tableUsers.style.borderSpacing = "0";
tableUsers.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
tableUsers.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Then the table is populated with 2 columns, one for the text and one for a small icon in front of it :

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var row = this.tableUsers.insertRow(i);
    row.style.height = "17px";

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style.width = "8px";

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.style.width = "55px";
    cell2.style.fontSize = "13px";
    cell2.style.color = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
    cell2.innerHTML = tab[i].name;
}
```

With these settings the string entries are nicely packed, but then adding the icon on the first row :

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
{
    var newImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    newImg.src = whiteDot;
    newImg.style.verticalAlign = "3px";
    tds[i].appendChild(newImg);
}
```

It messes up all the spacing. I tried setting `display` on the images with no success. How can I prevent it ? Thanks

Comment: A fiddle would be much helpful to identify the issue?

Comment: ah thanks for the tip, I just never used it yet